# How to import composables into server/api in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3

I just unified a `useSupabase` composable to remove duplicate code and to have access to the supabase context.

But I get an error when I import the composable into the server/api folder:

> message "useSupabase is not defined"

```js
// composables/useSupabase.js
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
const useSupabase = () => {
  const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY)
  return {
    supabase
  }
}
export default useSupabase
```

```js
// server/api/login.js
export default async (event) => {
  const body = await useBody(event)
  const { supabase } = useSupabase()

  const { user } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email: body.email,
    password: body.password
  })
  return user
}
```

Is there a way to import the composable into the endpoint?

#### another try

```js
// server/api/logout.js
import { supabase } from '~/composables/useSupabase.js'

export default async () => {
  let { error } = supabase.auth.signOut()
  return error
}
```

#### another import suggested by Bo

```js
// server/api/logout.js
import useSupabase from '~/composables/useSupabase.js'

export default async () => {
  const supabase = useSupabase()
  let { error } = supabase.auth.signOut()
  return error
}
```

> Error 500 "Cannot read property 'signOut' of undefined"

Comment: Seems that the endpoints are excluded in the nitro environment `.nuxt/types/nitro.d.ts` and my composable is in `.nuxt/types/auto-imports.d.ts`. Don't know what are the next steps.

Comment: same problem. Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: @witthenstein, Any solution? I need to use my supabase context/instance in the server folder. How do I import it?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik you can use your SUPABASE_KEY and SUPABASE_URL in your endpoint and write a simple `fetch`. Like:  `fetch(SUPABASE_URL, { method: 'POST', headers: {  'apikey': SUPABASE_KEY, ...`

Comment: I wanted to do, how were doing. The method u have suggested is not clear.

Comment: it works for me using a `fetch()`. Maybe it's better to create a new question on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually not Supabase related, it is Nuxt 3 currently doesn't support auto imports within the `server` directory, as Nuxt docs mentioned it here https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/concepts/auto-imports

Comment: thanks. What about a normal import statement? My login works fine and then for the logout I get an error `Rollup error:  'supabase' is not exported by composables/useSupabase.js, imported by server/api/logout.js`

Comment: can you share your logout.js code?

Comment: added the code above

Comment: if using direct import, you need to instantiate it by yourself: 

```
import useSupabase from '~/composables/useSupabase.js'

export default async () => {
  const supabase = useSupabaes()
  let { error } = supabase.auth.signOut()
  return error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got an `405` error: `HTTP method is not allowed`

Comment: can you give more details? when did you see 405 error? log in or log out?

Comment: updated the code above, @Bo

Comment: sorry my bad in typing the code, you should instantiate supabase like this `const { supabase } = useSupabase()`

Comment: No success, Bo. Got a `404`-error. But thanks to trying helping me out.

Comment: How do I import something like @nuxt/content queryContent() then?

Comment: Seems you can't `useNuxtApp` in the server context either...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple [limitations from rollup](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations) on the path. It needs to start with a hard-coded `./` or `../`.